# Speed up parsing of XML in Python to create Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, xml-parsing

I am parsing an XML file with 1.500.000 nodes, so I can dump the contents into a Pandas dataframe.

It does work well, but it's pretty slow (nearly 10 minutes!!) so I am wondering if you have some ideas to fix this process and do it faster. I read about using generators, but I am not sure this applies here, because I think that in order to parse, the full tree structure must be read in memory first (is that correct?)

Here is what I have so far, please let me know any suggestion for speed gains.

```
from lxml import etree as ET
import pandas as pd

def parse_xml_fields(file, base_tag, tag_list):
    final_list = []

    root = ET.parse(file)

    nodes = root.findall(".//{}".format(base_tag))
    for node in nodes:
        item = {}
        for tag in tag_list:
            try:
                item[tag] = node.find(".//{}".format(tag)).text.strip()
            except:
                item[tag] = ""

        final_list.append(item)

    return final_list

results = parse_xml_fields("15.1-EX_XML_EDR_UO.xml", "RECORD", 
        ["NAME","SHORT_NAME","EDRPOU","ADDRESS","BOSS","KVED","STAN","FOUNDER"])
df = pd.DataFrame(results)
```

If you are curious to test it out, you can get the XML from here: http://data.gov.ua./file/196445/download?token=Rmoh_lsA

It is a zip file which contains two XML. The one I am using is `15.1-EX_XML_EDR_UO.xml`

Comment: If you can share that xml for us to test, that would be better.

Comment: @Sraw, you are right, I have edited.

Comment: Have you tried Visitor pattern?

Comment: hi! did you solve this? I'm facing the same problem since -as I understand- the whole tree needs to be looped in order to get the data ... I cannot speed up this process of converting an xml file into a Padnas DF ...  :-(

Comment: @LucasAimaretto I never solved it as intended. I changed my architecture to do something else: I used Golang, which was faster and didn't choke with this size of XML and I outputted the results into a database instead of straight to a DF, so later I could use Pandas to read from there.